# lista basada en archivo json devuelve String

Tags: python, json, lista

tengo el siguiente problema:

```
def guardar_datos_en_json(dato, nombre_archivo):

try:
    with open(nombre_archivo, "a") as contenedor:
        json.dump(dato, contenedor)
except:
    raise

def cargar_datos_de_json(nombre_archivo):
lista = []    
with open(nombre_archivo,"r") as contenedor:
    for linea in contenedor:
        lista.append(linea)            
return lista
```

Esta función devuelve una lista basada en un archivo json, el problema es que cuando hago las pruebas correspondientes del programa que estoy creando, en vez de devolverme una lista, aparece un string en la lista, me explico:

Si por ejemplo guardo los números 1 y 2, cuando use la función cargar_datos_de_json devolverá ['12'] en lugar de [1, 2], porqué?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Porque cuando lees desde un archivo, lees todo como string, debes parsear o convertir el contenido a formato json, de lo contrario simplemente leeras siempre como string.

Comment: Y tenés algún método para hacer eso? Recién vi uno que incluye json.dumps(linea) pero no me funciona

Comment: Aquí encontré algo que podría ayudarte https://www.analyticslane.com/2018/07/16/archivos-json-con-python/